# Can VMWare Player use Win7 Unused RAM on 64-bit macxhine

Tags: windows-7, memory

I bought a laptop with 32GB of RAM and 64-bit intel corei7 machine running window 7 Home premium.

I found that Win7 Home premium only support up to 16GB RAM.
I am creating a virtual machine with VMware Player 6.0 for Ubuntu 12.04 to do some high end development work.

Can I allocate 16GB of unused RAM to this virtual machine? I wonder if VMWare Player can see all the installed 32GB RAM and use the wasted 16GB RAM.

/Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. If Windows' virtual memory manager sees only 16G physical memory due to licensing limitations, that's all you can use.

You may try one of these:

- install linux, and run VMWare player on linux with Win7 Home Ed.
- install a bare metal virtualization software instead of Windows, and run Windows & Ubuntu in a VM on it
- I think the best you can do is to upgrade the Windows license so you don't have to bother with these kind of problems